# How can I get a list of all methods in a certain class from c++ in mono?

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I've loaded my assembly "monoass.dll" using

```
mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "C:/monoass.dll");
```

then I found my class which name is "MainClass" using

```
mono_class_from_name(mono_assembly_get_image(ass), "monoass", "MainClass"); // where "monoass" is the name of namespace
```

then I need to find **all methods** in "MainClass" class as `MonoMethod**` array. How can I do this?

*Mono version is: Mono-3.2.3*

***Additional questions:***

1) How can I output the `MonoMethod`'s name, arguments and return value to the console? Is there any mono_method_to_string(MonoMethod* method) function?

2) How can I get all namespaces in my assembly (and print each name to the console) and then for each namespace get the array of all clases which are in the namespace?

Comment: You've probably already found your answer but for future reference : [`mono_class_get_methods`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=xhtml%3adeploy%2fmono-api-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all methods like this:

```
void* iter = NULL;
MonoMethod* method;
while(method = mono_class_get_methods(mono_class, &iter))
{
    cout << mono_method_full_name(method, 1);
}
```